# getblast error unavilable matlab

Tags: matlab, blast

I'm writing matlab code that's supposed to iterate over a list sequences and blast each at a time. Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
%blast the seq

[res, ROTE] = blastncbi(seq, 'blastn');
res1 = getblast(res, 'WaitTime',ROTE);
resName = res1.Hits(1).Name
```

for some seq's it worked, and then for the last it gave me this error message:

```
Error using getblast (line 176)
BLAST V7EBUE0901R is unavailable - try later.
```

please note that I've defined ROTE as the 'WaitTime' value, as suggested in the documentation of this function.

The script must iterate over lots and lots of genes, so I can't let it crash every 5 minutes!

Answer (score 0):

The `RTOE` returned by `blastncbi` is an *estimated* time of how long it takes. Perhaps the estimate is sometimes simply incorrect.

Two simple ways to deal with this could be waiting longer, or trying it twice:

```
res1 = getblast(res, 'WaitTime',ROTE*10);
```

or

```
try
   res1 = getblast(res, 'WaitTime',ROTE);
catch
   res1 = getblast(res, 'WaitTime',ROTE);
end
```

Of course this assumes that you are sure that the info that you request is actually available.